# AWS config files for Elastic Beanstalk don't work

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an old django project setup with elastic beanstalk using a .ebextensions folder.
This old project contains many files, some of which update Apache by putting configuration
files into the following location:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/
```

For example, it would add an enable_mod_deflate.conf by having the following command in one of the .ebextensions configuration files:

```
container_commands:
    01_setup_apache:
        # Setup gzip compression on apache server by copying enable_deflate.conf into appropriate directory.
        command: "cp .ebextensions/enable_mod_deflate.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_deflate.conf"
```

Similarly there is a file for cache configuration that looks something like this:

```
files:
    "/etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_cache.conf":
        mode: "000444"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            <IfModule mod_expires.c>
                ExpiresActive on
                ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
                ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
                ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
                ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
                ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
                ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
                ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month”
                ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month”
                ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 month"
                ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
            </IfModule>
```

The problem that I have is that I have just tried to create another Django project.   When I ssh into the old ec2 instance (I am using a single instance elastic beanstalk environment), I can see all of the files in the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ directory.   However when I use the new elastic beanstalk environment and look in the /etc/httpd/conf.d directory, none of the configuration files are created.

Its almost like AWS has changed elastic beanstalk so that it cannot copy to the conf.d directory.

I have downloaded the logs and cannot find anything to explain why the copy has stopped working.

It was over a year ago when I setup the original Django project, so I may be wrong about this, but it has an option to select nginx as the server, so I had to specifically pick Apache.   It feels like something has changed.

Does anybody have any idea's about why this isn't working and what I can do about it ?

Comment: Can you show us some of the relevant logs?

Answer (score 3):

You are using configuration files for `httpd` (`"/etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_cache.conf`) based on Amazon Linux 1 (AL1). However, for EB **platform based on AL2**, proxy `httpd` is setup differently then on AL1. Specifically, they should be in `.plaftorm` folder, not `.ebextentions`. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html#using-features.migration-al.generic):

> Configuration file location – You should place proxy configuration files in the .platform/nginx and **.platform/httpd** directories on all Amazon Linux 2 platform versions.

Further details how to setup `httpd` on AL2 platforms are in [Configuring Apache HTTPD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).